Use ! as literal char in the regex for Android Studio's TODO Filter
I'm following this official guide on how to set a custom TODO filter in Android Studio.
I need to implement an highlight for important comments that are not TODOs, like these:
// important: this note is much more important than other comment lines
// !!!: this note is also much more important than other comment lines
// normal comment

With this regex it works:
\bimportant\b.*

How to set the filter with !!!?
I tried these but without success:
\b!+\b.*
\b!!!\b.*
\b!+\b.*
\b\!+\b.*
\b\!\!\!\b.*
\b(important|\x0021)+\b.*


Do you mean you want to use word boundaries selectively, for both important and !!!? Then use (?!\B\w)(important|\x0021)(?!\B\w).*

@WiktorStribiżew it does work only for the comment // important: the comment, this will not be highlighted: // !!!: the comment

(?!\B\w)(important|!!!)(?!\B\w).*? I forgot to add + to the \x0021 (in PCRE, \x{0021}) in the top comment

@WiktorStribiżew you could just use (important|!!!)(?!\B\w).* if your making it like that, no need for the negative look ahead at the start

@KaranShishoo But that would match unimportant

@WiktorStribiżew make it (\bimportant:|!!!)(?!\B\w).* then, there is no need to add extra look aheads

As an aside, [!!!] is exactly equivalent to [!], which is exactly equivalent to !. The Stack Overflow regex tag info page has a short section about common beginner misunderstandings, including the meaning of square brackets.

@tripleee yep, I know it but in the mood of try everithing I tried also those :) thanks anyway ps. I remove it from the question

@WiktorStribiżew so, which one of the two working regex is the better one? yours: (?!\B\w)(important|!!!)(?!\B\w).* - @Karan: (\bimportant:|!!!)(?!\B\w).* and why? Also in terms of performances, thanks

@user2342558 It depends on what your requirements are: if you there are more words to cater for, and you do not know them beforehand, use both the lookaheads. If it is just the two alternatives, important and !!!, then you may simply use (\bimportant:|\B!!!\B).*. Please clarify your scenario.

@WiktorStribiżew both works, now the choice depends only for performance (I have 1000+ lines of code in a single java file)

for now I'll use this one: (\bimportant|!!!)(?!\B\w).*

The point is that your two alternatives start/end with different type of characters, word and non-word, and in this case you cannot blindly rely on the word boundaries, \b.
It appears your objective is to match two fixed alternatives, important and !!! as "whole words", but also be able to add more alternatives. In this case, you can use
(\bimportant|!!!)(?!\B\w).*

Here, \bi will match i only at the start of string or right after a non-word char, and (?!\B\w) will require a word boundary only if the preceding matched char is a word character, else, no word boundary will be required.
Here are examples how you can extend the pattern to include c++:
(\bimportant|!!!|\bc\+\+)(?!\B\w).*

Here are examples how you can extend the pattern to include --args:
(\bimportant|!!!|--args)(?!\B\w).*

The most generic solution is to use (?!\B\w) both at the start and end:
(?!\B\w)(important|!!!)(?!\B\w).*

That way, you do not lose much efficiency but you gain flexibility and you do not need to care about which alternatives start or end with non-word chars.

If you want to allow --args but not something--args you need some more tweaks still.

@tripleee That would require a non-word boundary if the word starts with a non-word char, so we'd need (?:\B(?!\w)|\b(?=\w)) at the start instead of (?!\B\w) (demo).

What you are missing is that ! counts as a symbol and not as a part of a word, hence \b does not see/identify a word boundary around it. You would need to use something like !!!.* to capture the line with 3 !
Adding proof from regex101:

secondary regex based on comments -
(\bimportant:|!!!)(?!\B\w).*

which covers both use cases.

It doesn't work. The !!! comment will not be highlighted, please post the full regex to try it

@user2342558 Please look at https://regex101.com/r/4pIbYi/1 it highlights the comment that has !!!

please edit your post with the complete regex as in your comment, so I can upvote your answrer (I did not downtoved it)

@user2342558 I have added the regex from the comments

But it is not YOUR regex. Please remove the post and I will post my solution myself.

@WiktorStribiżew both my initial regex as well as the one that was modified based on your computational expensive regex work despite even providing proof that you could simply use !!!.* to cover that case I could make the same case that the !!! was not YOUR regex but at that point it just becomes pedantic and unhelpful to actually helping people with problems which is the point of this site
